# React problem routing : no need re-rendering on second time

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I’m making a simple app with react-routing component.When user enter in /config path, it open a configuration page where he can choose element from select.

After this, user save data and the application set state of main component correctly (App.js). Then i make a “view change” using history to return in home (/ path).

The problem is : if user click on second time in /config routes, it lose all previous change made on DOM and it seems to be a new istance.

How i can preserve user interaction after first change? I cannot understand if i need to make a state inside this (Config.js) or there are an alternative solution.

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an app level configuration which should be preserved between renders/navigation you should consider using some sort of a state management like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) or you should store your config inside `sessionStorage`/`localStorage` (`sessionStorage` keeps track only while your browser tab is active = not closed. localStorage saves for the future when user closes and reopens your app).

Learn more about [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) on how to use `sessionStorage` and `localStorage`.

**NOTE:** When you navigate away from your component, it gets unmounted which means that the component's state is destroyed/trashed. That's probably the situation you're facing now with your project.

You need to store the data/state/config somewhere. If it's just a few things (nothing heavy or complex), you can use `localStorage` (it saves the data between sessions, doesn't matter if you close tab and open it again)... But if you need to have a greater control over the app's state you should consider diving into Redux Store.

Have in mind that by default redux doesn't support data persistence so you'll need to plug-in [Redux Persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) package to achieve that (it's like saving in localStorage, but now the whole Redux (with all the states) will be saved between sessions)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by

> lose all previous change made on DOM

Where do you store these changes made and could you not check for this state and render the contents of the **/config** component or even the component itself depending on whether or not the changes to the state have been made?